# xlsread ('not the file name but a string contained in an element of an array that is the file name)

Tags: excel, matlab

I would like to read an excel file (xlsread) but I don't want to put manually the string every time but instead I want to xlsread the name of the file that is contained in an array.

For example, my array B is:

```
B =
'john.xlsx'
'mais.xlsx'
'car.xlsx'
```

Then I would like to read the excel WITH THE NAME that is inside the first element, that means:  "john.xlsx"

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = xlsread(B{1});
```

Or, if you want to read all of them:

```
for i=1:length(B)
    data(i).nums = xlsread(B{i});
end
```

Assuming, of course, your B is a cell array. If it's not, it can't exist the way you described it. If all strings have the same length (then it would be possible) or padding with spaces, you can split the char array into a cell array using

```
B = mat2cell(B,ones(size(B,1),1),size(B,2));
```

Comment: Thank you for the replay. I didn't know I could use the curly brackets, that and the hint for the "for loop" solved my problem :). Actually I didn't use "(i).nums", but I tried the first time and it output was strange. Anyway, thanks for the hints that solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Strings of different lengths would have to be inside a cell array, which you can access elements via the curly brackets `{}`. So, you can call `xlsread` on the first element this way:

```
names{1} = 'john.xlsx';
names{2} = 'mais.xlsx';
names{3} = 'car.xlsx';

num = xlsread(names{1});
```